# Question about frequency moments

Tags: approximation, cardinals, estimation

I understand the F0 estimators find the cardinality of a multiset (Number of distinct elements).

Does an F1 estimator estimate the number of distinct elements that have appeared at least 2 times in the multiset?
And F-k estimator estimates the number of distinct elements that appeared at least k times in the multiset?